# How to create a typed dataset via the designer

Tags: asp.net, typed-dataset

I need to create a typed dataset using vs.net 2008.

It is not based on a database table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a dataset to the project by adding a new item.Let's say you name your dataset "myDataSet".

Open the myDataSet in designer mode, richt click, you will find "ADD"-> "DataTable".

Thanks,
rAm.